# how to write a query to get product ids contributing to top 80% sales?

Tags: sql

suppose i have a product is and sales column

```
product id sales
1            1000
2            10000
3            50000
4            12000
5             8000
```

write an sql query to get all product ids that contribute to top 80 % of sales?

Answer (score 3):

For this, you want a cumulative sum.  Presumably, you want the top selling such products, so:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             sum(sales) over (order by sales desc) as running_sales,
             sum(sales) over () as total_sales,
      from products
     ) p
where running_sales - sales < 0.8 * total_sales;
```

This returns the product that reaches or first exceeds 80% of the total sales.